# isAuthenticated annotation does not prevent access

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/payments")
public class PaymentController {
    @Autowired
    PaymentService paymentService;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(@Valid @RequestBody DownPayment downpayment) {

        Customer customer;
        Charge charge;
        User user = new User();
       ............
   }


}
```

WebSecurity config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

I want to use preAuthorize annotation (method level) instead of http security. The payments/create endpoint is publicly accessible which works without throwing any unauthorised error.

Comment: What does your `AuthenticationManager` implementation look like?

Comment: No AuthenticationManager implementation exist.

Comment: OK. Then what is your auth provider? And do you not have any other security configuration that authenticates the user?

Comment: Default auth provider by spring boot.

Comment: @VivekSadh Check, if your configuration is executed. It has to be in the component scan path or in a sub-package of your Spring Boot application class. Show your package structure.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint and check what is contained in the `SecurityContextHolder`, e.g. like that: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`. I suggest you add what is contained in the `SecurityContextHolder` to your question so that people can help you better.

My assumption is that you have [anonymous access enabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#anonymous), which means that an anonymous authentication object is placed in the `SecurityContextHolder` if no other authentication was set (e.g. by a `AuthenticationTokenFilter`). Spring detects this as an authentication, so that the access to your API is not prevented by the `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` annotation. Generally you should consider if it might not be better to use role-based access rules, as these are more fine-granular.

You can disable anonymous access as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .anonymous().disable()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
```